# Request a MS Graph Access token from Middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner

I'm trying to request MS Graph API from an API Middleware, in ASP.Net, to create programmatically Office Planners on specific api calls.

Customers are logged in to the frontend application via Azure AD SSO (using adal).
This access token allow users to authenticate to my api.

Now, i want to request a MS Graph access token from this API access token, to create the planners from the authenticated user account (on behalf of).

How can i proceed ?

Could the OBO flow (On-Behalf-Of flow) work in this case ?

Comment: You have your own frontend application and has integrated Azure AD, so I think you can generate access token in your frontend app, then you can this token to call graph api in your frontend app, no need to send the token to the backend server, I mean you don't need to use on behalf of flow.

Comment: Yes but it would bring business Logic to the front-end. What could be done would be to request graph access token from the front side and send it to backend on API when needed.

Comment: yes that's it. If you worried about adding too much business code in frontend, then you can also send the token to your backend first then call graph api.

Comment: And in backend app, when you have access token, you can use graph client or sending http request. `var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) =>{var token = accessToken;request.Headers.Authorization =new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);}));
var user = await _graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();`

Answer (score 0):

What Tiny Wang has said is correct, you could do that in Program.cs then use dependency injection for the Graph client inside your controller.

Here's a quick example below of posting an event to the authenticated users calendar.

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers;

[Authorize][AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
public class HomeController: Controller {
  private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphClient;

  public HomeController(GraphServiceClient graphClient) {
    _graphClient = graphClient;
  }

  public async Task AddUserCalendarEvent() {
    var @event = new Event {
      Subject = "Testing",
      Body = new ItemBody {
        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
        Content = "Test Body"
      },
      Start = new DateTimeTimeZone {
        DateTime = "2022-02-18T12:00:00",
        TimeZone = "Europe/London"
      },
      End = new DateTimeTimeZone {
        DateTime = "2022-02-18T12:00:00",
        TimeZone = "Europe/London"
      }
    };

    await _graphClient.Me.Events.Request().AddAsync(@event);
  }
}
```